# get an error trying right_click for Selenium Webriver

Tags: page-object-gem

I am using Ruby/Cucumber

my page:

```
class DemoContextMenuPage
    include PageObject
    include DataMagic

    page_url 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/context_menu'

    h5(:context_menu_title, :css => '.example > h3:nth-child(1)')
    div(:context_menu_hotspot, :id => 'hot-spot')
end
```

my step:

```
When /^I right click context menu hot spot$/ do
    on(DemoContextMenuPage).context_menu_hotspot_element.right_click
end
```

my feature:

```
Scenario: Verify right click menu
    Given I am on the context menu page
    When I right click context menu hot spot
```

result:
 undefined method `context_click' for # (NoMethodError)

no issues with watir-webdriver only selenium-webdriver Se=2.53.4, watir=0.9.3

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Page Object gem. You can see from the [page object's Selenium implementation](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/183d827e6bef7c57475913bc152d1fd49184b1c7/lib/page-object/platforms/selenium_webdriver/element.rb#L171-L173) that it does:

```
def right_click
  element.context_click
end
```

`context_click` is not a method defined for Selenium elements.

As seen from the [Watir source code](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/547992adf1ef8b570090387bbc6130435f1b3e9b/lib/watir/elements/element.rb#L160-L166), context clicks need to be done using the action builder:

```
driver.action.context_click(@element).perform
```

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to get the Selenium::WebDriver from a Selenium::Element. I think you will need to call the context click from the page object:

```
on(DemoContextMenuPage) do |page|
  e = page.context_menu_hotspot_element.element
  page.browser.action.context_click(e).perform
end
```